# Python json.loads() returns list instead of dict

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have the following json from a API i'm getting via requests.get(). 
Now I want to turn this json into a dict with json.loads() but the outcome is a list. 
From https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp the outcome should be a dict... or am I wrong here? Thanks!

```py
    import requests
    import json

    r = requests.get('http://url/api,                  
    auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('user','pass'))

    x = json.loads(r.text)

    # type(x) >>> <class 'list'>


json:
[
    {
        "id": 400285,
        "statusId": 1,
        "deliveryAddress": {
            "firstName": "Admin",
            "lastName": "Admin",
            "company": "Testshop 2",
            "street": "Teststr. 1",
            "houseNumber": "",
            "additionalAddressInfo": "",
            "postcode": "12345",
            "city": "Testort",
            "state": "Bremen",
            "country": "Germany",
            "countryIsoCode": "DE"
        },
        "billingAddress": {
            "firstName": "Admin",
            "lastName": "Admin", 
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 400288,
        "statusId": 1,
        "deliveryAddress": {
            "firstName": "Carolin",
            "lastName": "Pr\u00f6ger",
            "company": "",
            "street": "teststra\u00dfe 12",
            "houseNumber": "",
            "additionalAddressInfo": "",
            "postcode": "12345",
            "city": "Bremen",
            "state": "Bremen",
            "country": "Germany",
            "countryIsoCode": "DE"
        },
        "billingAddress": {
            "firstName": "Carolin",
            "lastName": "Pr\u00f6ger",
        }
    }
]
```

Edit1:

```py
mydict= {}

for item in mylist:
    mydict['ID'] = item['id']
    mydict['statusID'] = item['statusId']
```

Comment: ...your JSON is literally a list, there's nothing wrong here.

Comment: ah thanks... can i turn this somehow (easy way) into a dict?
I think it would be easier to proceed. my outcome should be a .csv. and i got more objects than this one.

Comment: Can the solution to get a clean json, to cut first six chars and last 2 chars? 
E.g.: mytext = r.text[6:-2]? 
(it's somehow not working :D)

Comment: Your json is a ```list``` of ```dict```. What are you trying to achieve? What is the key/value you are trying to get.

Comment: well.. this is the output of an api, with several objects in this "json" (is it even json? i'm still learning...) 
I want to filter out relevant information, e.g. only "id" and "statusId" and either export those to a .csv or .xls (pandas?) but pandas is only working with dict... or is there a better way? i'm open for suggestions :)

Comment: A json file is basically a string readable format file. So it does look like one, but at the same time there are typos in it. I am not sure about Pandas, so I will let others respond to it. But if you are looking to pair id/statusId you can use a for loop and create your own dict first.

Comment: Something like this: ```my_dict = {item['id']: item['statusId'] for item in json_response}```

Comment: Thanks, Nic. I added a new loop (not single line, just for my learning) in question above (Edit1). But it's not working. Could you help me out to find my mistake?

Comment: for me was inside the list there is dict

Answer (score 0):

The data type returned from json.load is assigned depending of the data structure of the json file.
Your json file has [] (list structure).
But you need your json file to have {} (list structure).

Answer (score -1):

It is because of your json response contains list not object.

Comment: List is an object. We have already stated that his json was a list. Nothing added here.