# Looping through array of objects in json file downloaded from S3

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, boto3

I am getting a json file from S3 using boto3 get_object. I need to get the contents from the file and loop through the array of objects and get one object at a time. When I loop through I get one character per iteraration.

import json
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
session = boto3.Session()

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event["bucket"]
    key = event["key"]

    data = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    contents = data['Body'].read()

    test = contents.decode("utf-8")

    # convert contents to native python string representing json object
    s3_string = json.dumps(contents.decode("utf-8"))

    # return dict
    s3_dict = json.loads(s3_string)

    # this seems to output valid json
    # print(str(s3_dict))

    for item in s3_dict:
        print(item)
```

The json in the file is formatted as follows

```
[{
        "location": "123 Road Dr",
        "city_state": "MyCity ST",
        "phone": "555-555-5555",
        "distance": "1"
    },
    {
        "location": "456 Avenue Crt",
        "city_state": "MyTown AL",
        "phone": "555-867-5309",
        "distance": "0"
    }
]
```

This is what I get (one character per iteration)...

1. [
2. {
3. "
   ...

This is what I need (in json format)...

1st loop

```
{
        "location": "123 Road Dr",
        "city_state": "MyCity ST",
        "phone": "555-555-5555",
        "distance": "1"
    }
```

2nd Loop

```
 {
        "location": "456 Avenue Crt",
        "city_state": "MyTown AL",
        "phone": "555-867-5309",
        "distance": "0"
    }
```

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the indentation the same as you have it in the post? If so, that doesn't look correct.

Comment: No. The indentation is correct and it builds fine. I am just not getting the output I need. I will fix the indentation.

Comment: Are you sure? There's several indents between the first and second lines of the Python snippet.

Comment: Yes, I just copied and pasted. It's not all the code either. Just a sample. If the indentation was off in my actual code I would get an error. I am not getting an error and I am getting output from each iteration of the loop.That output is just not what I was expecting.

Comment: What's the output of `print(str(s3_dict))`? I'm not able to reproduce the issue you're describing.

Comment: The output of print(str(s3_dict)) is valid json. I can copy it into JsonLint and it validates fine.

Comment: Is it the same as what's in the file? If so, I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: The json is in the format I described in the  json file in S3. I can't give the actual data in the file because it contains confidential information

Comment: Okay. But, to be clear, `print(str(s3_dict))` produces the contents of the file?

Comment: Yes. After I download the file from S3 using boto3 get_object the print(str(s3_dict)) produces what is in the file. Something is clearly going wrong though, because I can't loop through s3_dict and get the expected output.

Comment: What's the type of `s3_dict`?

Comment: I'm newish to python but I believe json.loads should give you a python dictionary. Another reason I am confused that it is producing valid json. Maybe putting str around it produces that result.

Comment: Is there more than one quote around `s3_dict` when you `print()` it? I would also check what the type of it is, just to be sure.

Comment: Ok - I will check in the morning. Thanks for the help.

Comment: As mentione3d previously, the code you display should give a error. The line starting with `for` should be at the same level as the previous `print`. If this is not the full code, please provide a minimum reproducible code

Comment: I wrote a scaled down version of the lambda function and tested it to reproduce the issue. I edited the original post.

Comment: Use `s3_string = contents.decode("utf-8")` to get the string before running `json.loads` it, as it is now, you're serializing an serialized object.

Comment: Thanks @AnonCoward. That got me on the right track. I was sure I was doing something stupid like that. :-) There was another issue  with my assuming json.loads would always return a dict., so I am going to post my working solution in case anyone else makes the same assumption. or needs to do something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the working solution.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event["bucket"]
    key = event["key"]

    data = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    contents = data['Body'].read()

    # convert contents to native python string representing json object
    s3_string = contents.decode("utf-8")

    # check the "type" of s3_string - in this case it is <class 'str'>
    print("s3_string is " + str(type(s3_string)))

    # return python list
    s3_list = json.loads(s3_string)

    # check the "type" of s3_list - in this case it is <class 'list'>
    print("s3_list is " + str(type(s3_list)))

    # this returns valid json for every object in the array in original json file.
    for item in s3_list:
        print(json.dumps(item))
```

I had assumed I was getting a python dict as this in the default behavior of json.loads. I was in fact getting a list. This explains why...
[Json file gets load as list instead of dict. using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62834614/json-file-gets-load-as-list-instead-of-dict-using-python)